# php not echoing error message if data is missing - instead displaying php fatal error

Tags: php

I am using PHPMailer in order to build a contact form and I am looking for a variable ($msg) to display a success or failure message depending on if the end user has correctly filled out the form or not.   The ($msg) variable echo's succesfully if the form is completed correctly however, the $(msg) variable does not echo if the user does not fill out the form correctly and instead I receive a fatal error which reads as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: Invalid address: (Reply-To): in /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1004 Stack trace: #0 /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(973): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addOrEnqueueAnAddress('Reply-To', '', '') #1 /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/contactForm.php(18): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->addReplyTo('') #2 /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/contactForm.php(30): sendemail('info@purplelime...', '', '', '') #3 /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/index.php(9): include('/home/k4piavsj0...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1004

Here's my code, does anyone have any ideas how I get the ($msg) variable to display if the end user has not completed the form or it has failed from the server side?

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

    function sendemail ($to, $reply, $subject, $body) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'PLT Contact Form - Email');
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->addReplyTo($reply);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->IsHTML(false);

        return $mail->send();
    }

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    if (sendemail('info@test.com', $email, $subject, $body)) {
        $msg = 'Email has been sent, Thank you!';
    } else
        $msg = 'Email failed, please try again later';

  }

?>


<html>

<title>Contact Form Using PHPMailer</title>


<body>

    <div id="contactInnerWrapper">
        <a href="#"><span id="close">&times;</span></a>
        <h1 id="h1contactForm">Get in touch</h1>
            <form method="post" action="contactForm.php">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
                <input  type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter email" id="email">
                <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input  type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
                <label for="body">What would you like to ask us?</label><br>
                <textarea  type="text" name="body" rows="7" id="content"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <br><br>
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do your question (in bold font) does have anything in common with that error above? I would say “Invalid address” is a clear enough – pass a valid email address into `$_POST['email']` and you will see a result. Would be be better though, to check if the given email address is a valid one

Comment: Adding some data validation might do the trick. Never assume that you get all the data you need in the format you expect from the user. Rule of thumb, _never_ trust user data.

Comment: Also surround the call to `sendemail` with `try, catch PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception` and set the error message on the catch clause

Comment: Use Try catch for better error handling : 
try { // your code }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I'm very new to PHP so all the suggestions you are providing are very much appreciated but unfortunately I am unable to understand some of the terminologies you are referring to.  Could I ask that some code is provided so that I can see where I am going wrong and can try and get it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last if statement to this

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // 
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($subject) && !empty($body)) {
    try {
        if (sendemail('info@purplelimetree.com', $email, $subject, $body))
            $msg = 'Email has been sent, Thank you!';
        else
            $msg = 'Error sending email';
    }catch(Excpetion $e) {
        $msg = 'Sending email failed, error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
} else
    $msg = 'Email failed, incomplete/invalid data';
```

1. Remove all illegal characters from email with FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL.
2. The FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL filter validates an e-mail address.
3. Check if not empty body and subject.
4. Try sending the email and on fatal error properly catch it and return an explanatory message.
5. If `sendemail` function return correctly set success message or else set error message.

Comment: A little info on what you changed and why you changed it could be helpful for OP

Comment: when I run the code and submit the form as incomplete the page just goes blank with no error messages and nothing showing in the console?

Comment: @Coder In my code I **set** the error message, do you **print** the message at any point? I don't see an `echo` statement at the original part of your code you provided.

Comment: I echo it on the html file, I will upload html code now for you to see.  Hopefully you can help!

Comment: html as now been added :)

Comment: @Coder the error is in your `$msg` variable now. you just have to use `echo($msg)` or `print($msg)` anywhere you want to see the occured error or simply the success message...

Comment: I am echoing in HTML part of the code and the success msg displays fine but when it is the error message it does not display and shows the fatal error.  The fatal error is correct as in phpmailer is doing what its meant to but I do not want to display this, I want to display the failed msg defined by me

Comment: @Coder `<form method="post" action="testContactForm.php" class="ajax">` current filename is `contactForm.php` and not `testContactForm.php` as I can see and what is the `class="ajax"` you submit your form by Ajax?

Comment: @Coder just replace `}catch(Excpetion $e) {
        $msg = 'Sending email failed, error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }` by `}catch(Excpetion $e) {
        $msg = 'Error sending email';
    }`

Comment: Please ignore ajax for the moment as I have disabled this in order to test PHP on its own.  Sorry please also ignore the difference in the file name as it is correct on the final code I'm using.  I accidentally uploaded the old HTML code (i'm not having a good day! haha)

Comment: @Coder please update your code to its current state or else we are unable to help. For what I can see everything should work correct regarding the `sendmail`, I believe the error is somewhere else. Please provide your full php file.

Comment: @Elementary - tried this and unfortunately, it goes to a blank screen again with no errors in the console.

Comment: @Theofanis I have now updated the code.  The PHP supplied is all of the PHP in the file.

Comment: @Coder the final *contactForm.php* file should be exactly [this](https://3v4l.org/ojiTm). After that I give up.

Comment: It works now on the failed message (awesome!) but now there is an error notice on the success message.  The notice says: Notice: Use of undefined constant subject - assumed 'subject' in /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/cleverbubbles.com/testContactForm.php on line 30

Notice: Use of undefined constant body - assumed 'body' in /home/k4piavsj0bsc/public_html/cleverbubbles.com/testContactForm.php on line 30

I feel like we are really close now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Coder yeah sorry my mistake, forgot '$' signs, update the if statement with this `if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($subject) && !empty($body)) {` added '$' sign before 'subject' and 'body' [here](https://3v4l.org/86EV6)

Comment: Awesome & Awesome!  It's working, thanks for all your help and efforts!  I just need to go back over your code and work out exactly what you did to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you understand and solve your problem.

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']:'';
$subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject']:'';
$body = isset($_POST['body']) ? $_POST['body']:'';

$is_valid_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

$status = false;
if ($email!='' && $is_valid_email==true && $subject!='' && $body!='') {
    $status = sendemail('info@purplelimetree.com', $email, $subject, $body)
}
if($status==true){
    $msg = 'Email has been sent, Thank you!';
} else
    $msg = 'Email failed, please try again later';
}
```

Comment: This only checks if `email` has a value, not that it contains a valid email address. Also, in PHP7+, you can use the short hand `$email = $_POST['email'] ?? null;` instead.

Comment: Email validation added before calling `sendemail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to change config php.ini file in your php handling module setting**

1.go to your module (Like xampp apache ).

2.open config file

3.search for error_reporting (Here you will see the error what type of error reporting your module is giving for php program test.)

4.**error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING** set error reporting like this;

By doing that you are get all error but not warning and fetal error